# Google Cloud Shell unable to display files present in Google Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

[image: Google cloud error]

Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wppyv.png) available clearly shows that the bucket contains a folder namely cloudml-samples-master and a file namely setup.py

However on entering the command **ls** in Google Cloud Shell, it is giving no output. I am stuck at this problem and I have tried almost everything but I am unable to find the reason behind this.

Also when I am trying to access these files through my API, I get an error displaying that these files could not be found.

Both the files present in the directory were uploaded using WebUI.

To add my opinion, what I understood till now is that the files being uploaded using WebUI and those uploaded using command line are acting independently. Because I have seen that the files which I am uploading using command line are not showing in UI. Is there some error from my side or is it an issue related with Cloud Google Storage?

Comment: How have you tried to upload files to your bucket? In general, you need to use the `gsutil` tool in order to interact with Cloud Storage from the Shell. I do not really understand how are you trying to access the bucket. Have you mounted it in the machine running the Shell? Where does that *gs:/...* folder point to?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below from https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features, Google Cloud Shell is not connected directly with Google Cloud Storage. It gives you possibility to connect with that storage eg. via gsutil

> **When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a g1-small Google Compute
>   Engine virtual machine** running a Debian-based Linux operating system.
>   Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session
>   basis.

Also:

> Cloud Shell provides the following:
>
> A temporary Compute Engine virtual machine instance Command-line
>   access to the instance from a web browser Built-in code editor BETA
>   **5 GB of persistent disk storage** Pre-installed Google Cloud SDK and other tools Language support for Java, Go, Python, Node.js, PHP, Ruby
>   and .NET Web preview functionality Built-in authorization for access
>   to GCP Console projects and resources